# Embedding Application to my website

Tags: java, php, jsp, jakarta-ee, embed

I have one doubt it may be wired or may be possible i dont know!

Example, I have a VLC player or u can take any other application like Games or so , Is it possible to embed that application to my PHP,JSP,J2ee or any other programming which will allow users to use those application online.

Is it possible to do so , Please guide me about this as i have searched a lot but i could'n get things on my way. Do i need to learn something new or can use java/php/asp or anything that makes this possible.

Comment: This question is way to broad. But I guess the general answer is: no you can't simply embed any application in your website. Then, it also depend on what you mean with "embed"...

Comment: embed here means like i want my vlc software to be used online some thing like that. Is there any thing that i can read to make this possible. I dont care how complex it is ill start learning from the next moment

Comment: You may try streaming a video of the application to the user, and validating user input (if the user clicks on the stream or presses keyboard keys). This approach requires a big effort for each single user. For Gaming see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_gaming

Comment: "used online something like that" is what makes the difference. As I said before, this question is too broad to be discussed here